# Show scaled UIViewController in another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to display a scaled down "preview" of another `ViewController` in another `ViewController`. Is this possible? No interaction are needed so it can basically be a screenshot, but scaled down. I can be solved by manually take a screenshot and save it as an image, but the `ViewController` contains a lot of localizations and are constantly updated, so if this can be done programatically.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kd5vinrym1k7afk/Screenshot%202014-05-13%2015.20.17.png

Is this possible?

Edit: the sub view is stored in a storyboard

Edit: This is how I've solved it:

```
//Load the viewcontroller and view
previewViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[PLACEHOLDER_VIEWCONTROLLER_NAMES objectAtIndex:self.identifier]];
[self addChildViewController:previewViewController];
[self.placeholderView.superview addSubview:previewViewController.view];
previewViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale*2, scale*2);
CGPoint center = self.placeholderView.center;
center.y += 25;
previewViewController.view.center = center;
```

Comment: Like you said it.. take a screenshot and scale down the image!

Comment: It would be to time consuming to do this for every language every time the layout gets updated, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `viewController.view` and then scale it down like:

```
viewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
```

Comment: I also need to add a view controller to another view controller first. I fear that's the big issue.

Comment: I don't get what you mean and why this should be a problem. Why can't you access the viewController.view that you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

```
Add your another view controller view as subview to first viewcontroller


[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{

    InnerView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    //Always starts from original scale
    InnerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);

    //Incremental scale
    //InnerView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(InnerView.transform, 0.5, 0.5);


} completion:^(BOOL finished) {


    NSLog(@"in Half size");

}];




[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{

    InnerView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;


} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    InnerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    NSLog(@"Normal size");


}];
```

Comment: Yes, decreasing the size of a view is fairly simple. But how do I add a viewcontroller and view to another viewcontroller/view? The subview is located in a storyboard.